# Cache Managing for MVC can not keep value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, model-view-controller

When I use below code in webform.aspx I can have value even after stopping project.
But when I am workinh with MVC , I can not have it with controller.
Could you tell me why.

DateTime? date1 = (DateTime?)HttpContext.Cache["MyKey"];

```
        if (!date1.HasValue) // date1 == null
        {
            date1 = DateTime.Now;
            HttpContext.Cache.Insert("MyKey", date1, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `Insert` if the key is initially null. Try this:

```c#
date1 = DateTime.Now;
if(HttpContext.Cache["MyKey"] == null){
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert("MyKey", date1, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
} else {
    HttpContext.Cache["MyKey"] = date1;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```c#
int NumberofDaysToCache = 2;
HttpContext.Cache.Insert("MyKey", date1, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(NumberofDaysToCache), 
System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Comment: as long as project is running I can get value but I wanna have value for example after two days.

Comment: You could extend the life of the cache to two days: `DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Dominic 
I am trying to keep data inside cache for more than one day via MVC ASP.NET 2017, I mean when I turn off system after more than one day my cache is still live.
 For testing , if I close visual studio, and again open I wanna see value inside cache.

In webform.aspx I could do that but in mvc controller when I wanna use cache i got error which says cache is a type and is not in this context.